# What is the "name" of this function?

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions

There is a function I met in complex analysis.
$$f(\lambda) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i\lambda x}}{\sqrt{1 + x^{2n}}}dx$$

Comment: Maple does something complicated in terms of the Meijer G function.

Comment: I read about McDonalds function,
$$
f(\lambda ) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{i \lambda x}dx}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}.
$$
It's one of the Bessel's function. Has the function from my question the name as the, maybe, Bessel's function?

Answer (score 3):

It's called the Fourier Transform of $\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^{2n}}}$.

Comment: I read about McDonald function,
$$
f( \lambda ) = \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{i \lambda x}dx}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}}.
$$
It's one of Bessel's function. Has the function from my question the name as the Bessel's function?

Comment: @Maxim_Ovchinnikov sorry I don' t know, but if I'll ever find something I'll let you know...